# Iterating through result set in Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to simply iterate though a result set in laravel on the controller side. This is what I tried but I get the following error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Controller snippet:

```
$result = DB::select($query);

foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r['email'];
}
```

I appreciate any help with this,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use it as an object:

```
$result = DB::select($query);

foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r->email;
}
```

Or if for some reason you want to use it as array, you need to convert it first:

```
$result = DB::select($query)->toArray();

foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After pulling data from database you can convert it to array but it is optional, it's depends on your necessity then you can simply use the **foreach** to loop through to each distinct object and get access their property

```
$data = DB:: table('categories')
                ->where('parent_id', $request->value)
                ->get()->toArray();
        $output = '<option value="">Select '.ucfirst($request->dependent).'</option>';
        foreach($data as $row){
            $output.= '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->title.'</option>';
        }
        return response($output, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel Collection class supports the standard methods for iterables: map, sort, filter etc. see: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php`

if you're querying on a model:

```
$results = MyAwesomeModel::where('something' '=' 'other')->get();

//this is valid
$results->map(function($result) {
  echo $result->field;
});

//this is also valid
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++){
  echo $results[$i]->field;
}
```

I would suggest avoiding `->toArray()` on hydrated results (instances of models) because you loose all the model properties.